# Compound sentence with a common verb and an article

Tags: grammar, clauses

I have the following set of compound sentences:

****She is a doctorate in physics, a soccer player, and a pianist.****

**She is a doctorate in physics and is a soccer player and a pianist.**

**She is a doctorate in physics, is a soccer player, and is a pianist.**

The first one is being objected by *Grammarly* as an incorrect construction since the article `a`'s are missing verbs (`be` verb here) after the commas. This has been corrected in the second sentence. However, repeating a common verb in a sentence appears ugly and cumbersome to me. Is there a pretty way of writing the same?

By the way, *Grammarly* does not object against any of these:

**She is a soccer player and a pianist.**

**She is a soccer player and pianist.**

She is a soccer player, pianist, and graduate. [`a` is common as well as `is`]

If I use

**She is a doctorate in physics, soccer player, and pianist.**

*Grammarly* cautions: *'Incomplete Sentences'*.

What part of the grammar book do I need to keep in mind to build a correct compound sentence?

Comment: Hello, hbaromega. People are referred to as doctors if they have a doctorate [degree].

Comment: None of your examples are compound sentences. They are either a coordination of NPs or VPs, e.g. "She is [a doctorate in physics], [a soccer player], and [a pianist]. / She [is a doctorate in physics], [is a soccer player], and [is a pianist], though the latter coordination is not at all natural.

Comment: It seems to me as if Grammarly's algorithms are picking up the sentence as *"She is a doctorate in physics, a doctorate in soccer player, and a doctorate in pianist."* This is probably caused by the misuse of "doctorate".

Comment: _She **has** a doctorate in physics_. Doctorates are degrees, people have them.

Answer (score 3):

People are referred to as doctors if they have a doctorate [degree]. I'll amend the example sentences:

- She is a Doctor of Physics, a soccer player, and a pianist.

This is grammatically fine; omission of the verb (and subject) after the first occurrence is normal in such sentences. Predictable elements can be and often are omitted. 'He is an officer and a gentleman' is a well known example using the copula (be).

- She is a Doctor of Physics[,] and is a soccer player[,] and a pianist.

Subject, then subject and copula, deleted. I actually prefer this version (equally grammatical), especially with the optional comma after the first list item, because academic achievement and possibly leisure activities are pretty distinct.

- She is a Doctor of Physics, is a soccer player, and is a pianist.

Also grammatical. Here, only the subject is deleted. It sounds rather starchy, staccato, but could be used to add emphasis. But I'd say a better way to do this would be to use three complete independent clauses (and I'd choose commas, and the 'and' before the last clause, to link them).

Answer (score 2):

> [1] She is [a doctorate in physics], [a soccer player], and [a pianist].
>
> [2] She [is a doctorate in physics] and [is [a soccer player] and [a pianist]].
>
> [3] She [is a doctorate in physics], [is a soccer player], and [is a pianist].
>
> [4] She is [a soccer player] and [a pianist].
>
> [5] She is a [soccer player] and [pianist].
>
> [6] She is a [doctorate in physics], [soccer player], and [pianist].

Preliminary point: these are not compound sentences with some element omitted, but coordinate constructions with various types of coordinate. The coordinates (bracketed) consist of:

[1] three noun phrases.
[2] two verb phrases, the latter containing a further coordination of two nominals.
[3] three verb phrases.
[4] two noun phrases.
[5] two nominals.
[6] three nominals.

They are all acceptable except [2] and [3] which are somewhat unnatural.