# The omission of the copula is

Tags: linking-verbs

I was on a plane and saw this, but I was not sure if another “is” is needed before the adjective punishable.

“Unauthorised removal of life vest is a criminal offense and punishable by law”

Comment: It may be omitted. _Unauthorised removal of [the] life vest is immoral, bad, wrong, wicked, stupid, dangerous,  a criminal offense[,] and punishable by law_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compound sentence with a common verb and an article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335071/compound-sentence-with-a-common-verb-and-an-article)

Comment: @Angyang  FumbleFingers has searched the archive of questions and has found a very similar question.  It is a question about whether another "is" is needed when there are two things.  The answer is given there.  The proper response to Fumblefingers is either "Thank you, that other question helps me" or "Thank you, but that other question doesn't help me because..."

Answer (score 2):

> *Unauthorised removal of life vest* ***is*** [*a criminal offense*] *and* [(*is*) *punishable*
> *by law*].

It's optional.

Your example contains a coordination of two phrases (bracketed) each functioning as predicative complements of "be".

A reliable test for grammatical coordination is to replace the coordination with either coordinate alone:

> *Unauthorised removal of life vest is a criminal offense.*
> *Unauthorised removal of life vest is punishable by law*.

The fact that both sentences are grammatical proves that the whole coordination is also grammatical.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. It just reads a bit strange to me at first glance. "Is a criminal offence and punishable by law," I simply didn't think they were coordinated this morning when I saw it